# no such file to load -- mysql (LoadError) - ruby gems

Tags: mysql, ruby, cucumber

I'm a newbie to ruby, trying to connect mysql servcer through Ruby for cucumber and getting the following error while running cukes.
error: no such file to load -- mysql (LoadError)

But installed mysql gem and here is my gem list and also has libmysql.dll under ruby_home\bin path

- addressable (2.2.8)
- builder (3.0.0)
- bundler (1.1.4)
- childprocess (0.3.3)
- cucumber (1.2.1)
- diff-lcs (1.1.3)
- ffi (1.0.11, 1.0.9 x86-mingw
- gherkin (2.11.1 x86-mingw32)
- headless (0.2.2)
- json (1.7.3)
- libwebsocket (0.1.4)
- minitest (1.6.0)
- multi_json (1.3.6)
- mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)
- mysql2 (0.3.11 x86-mingw32)
- net-ldap (0.3.1)
- rake (0.8.7)
- rdoc (2.5.8)
- rspec (2.10.0)
- rspec-core (2.10.1)
- rspec-expectations (2.10.0)
- rspec-mocks (2.10.1)
- rubygems-update (1.8.24)
- rubyzip (0.9.9)
- selenium-webdriver (2.24.0)
- titleize (1.2.1)
- watir-webdriver (0.6.1)

Any idea whats going on...

Comment: Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

What version of Ruby are you running mate? If you're running 1.8 you need to add "require 'rubygems'" before your "require 'mysql'. If not then try requiring the gem in a non-explicit way. Something like this:

```
require_relative "rubygems"    
require_relative "mysql"
```

If you want to give it a quick test use this code below..:

```
require "rubygems"   

require "mysql"

     begin

     # connect to the MySQL server

     db = Mysql.real_connect("localhost", "username", "password")


     # get server version string and display it

     puts "Server version: " + db.get_server_info


   rescue Mysql::Error => e

     puts "Error code: #{e.errno}"

     puts "Error message: #{e.error}"

     puts "Error SQLSTATE: #{e.sqlstate}" if e.respond_to?("sqlstate")

   ensure

     # disconnect from server

     db.close if db

   end
```

If all goes well you should see your mysql version..

Comment: I'm using Ruby 1.9 if I use require_relative "rubygems" getting cannot infer basepath from (irb):1:in `require_relative'           but if i use require "rubygems" / require "mysql - it returns true.

Comment: Use require "rubygems" / require "mysql then and it should work!

Comment: Have your mysql server running. Use your favourite txt editor and save this code above with an yourfilename.rb extension. Then run it from command prompt by typing ruby yourfilename.rb

Comment: I've just tested the above and I connected and got the version fine..let me know if you still have any problems..

Comment: I had 2 requires(require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql') in my rb file. I have executed above code and here is the error I'm seeing but where as I could connect to my DB from DB developer. Error: Error code: 2003 Error message: Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.7.20.9' (10061) Error SQLSTATE: HY000 => nil

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414581/mysql-connect-not-working-for-a-site)..one guy mentions that it could be down to your provider not allowing external connections..i'm not sure that is the case with you but out of curiosity try connecting to localhost as an experiment and not to 10.7.20.9 just to see if you can successfully connect

Comment: oh! and one more thing! could it be a firewall prohibiting you of connecting? try bringing all of your firewalls down if you can including router's internal firewall to see if that is the case..

Comment: I'm telnetting to that MYsql server and able to connect through MUSQL developer but not through ruby programming..it's really weird...